# Why primefaces textarea not showing red border in case of error?

Tags: primefaces

I'm using primefaces inputtextarea but in case of error it didn't shows the red border around it but shows only shows the error message.

```
 <p:messages id="message1"/>
 <p:inputTextarea id="INote" 
                  value="#{currenttrtevents.selectedtrtevent.issuesIdentified}" 
                  autoResize="false" 
                  required="true" 
                  requiredMessage="Issues Required"  
                  style="width:500px;height:170px;color:black !important;">
 </p:inputTextarea>

 <p:commandButton id="add"  
                 value="Add" 
                 oncomplete="if(!args.validationFailed) fIssuesDialog.hide()" 
                 actionListener="#{currenttrtevents.processIssues}" 
                 process="issuesFrm" 
                 update=":trtInfoForm,message1" global="false">
 </p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is example code that run test with primefaces 3.4.2, mojarra 2.1.17 on tomcat 7.0.55 and the red border is appear.

```
<h:form>
    <h3>AutoResize</h3>
    <p:inputTextarea id="textarea1" 
                     rows="6" 
                     cols="33" 
                     required="true" 
                     requiredMessage="Issues Required"/>
    <p:message for="textarea1" id="message1"/>
    <p:commandButton process="@form" 
                     update="textarea1,message1" 
                     value="submit"/>
</h:form>
```

Good luck.

Comment: i'm missing the inputtextarea update in commandbutton.Thank you for your help.